# How to improve this code in intelligente way in Jquery to change the background code of DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've 6 div's when the user clicks on the DIV it displays the contect of the divs. (I'm using ASPX - Ajaxtabpanel).

Below I figured out the div names and what I do below is, when the click on a DIV, change the Background color. So Active div get another color. Below I've JQuery code it works but I'm sure it can be done in better way.. what can I do to improve the code to use better functions of Jquery?

As you probably can see, all the DIV names start with same convention ... Just these middle words are different  Algemeen, Juridisch, Fiscaal, Economisch, Veiligheid...

Please advice how can I improve the code....

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function resetColor() {
//set all background colors of Div to blue
    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelAlgemeen_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#edf2fb");
    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelJuridisch_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#edf2fb");
    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelSociaal_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#edf2fb");
    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelFiscaal_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#edf2fb");
    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelEconomisch_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#edf2fb");
    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelVeiligheid_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#edf2fb");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  //Change the ACTIVE div background color

    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelAlgemeen_tab").click(function() {
        resetColor();
        $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelAlgemeen_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#80FE80");
    });
    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelJuridisch_tab").click(function() {
    resetColor();
        $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelJuridisch_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#80FE80");
    });
    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelSociaal_tab").click(function() {
    resetColor();
        $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelSociaal_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#80FE80");
    });
    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelFiscaal_tab").click(function() {
    resetColor();
        $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelFiscaal_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#80FE80");
    });
    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelEconomisch_tab").click(function() {
    resetColor();
        $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelEconomisch_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#80FE80");
    });
    $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelVeiligheid_tab").click(function() {
    resetColor();
        $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelVeiligheid_tab .ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#80FE80");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are the only divs that use class ajax__tab_outer, you could do something like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function resetColor() {
   $(".ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#edf2fb");
}

function changeColor() {
   resetColor();
   $(this).find(".ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#80FE80");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   // Bind all the divs to the changeColor function
   $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanelVeiligheid_tab").click(changeColor);
   ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: in your $(document).ready, you can also bind the changeColor function by "$('.ajax__tab_outer').click(changeColor);" i think...

Comment: I would prefer changing a classname than a css property also, for example, "selected" and "unselected" classes, with their background property in css... In javascript you change the classname. That way a designer can change the look of the website without knowing jquery/javascript.

Comment: Ok.. this code is working... is there anyway also to make the code shorter in document.ready e.g. in stead of putting 6 DIVS there just one with generic something like  start with this word (look at the * below?   $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_TabPanel*").click(changeColor);

Comment: You could assign each of these div a custom css class (let's say 'tabcontainer'). Then you could use a single line of code in the document.ready function. $('.tabcontainer').click(changeColor);

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
        $("span[id$='_tab']", "#<%= TabContainer1.ClientID %>").click(
        function () {
            $(".ajax__tab_outer", "#<%= TabContainer1.ClientID %>").css("background-color", "#edf2fb");
            $(".ajax__tab_outer", this).css("background-color", "#80FE80");
        });
    });
```

(fixed)

Comment: This is so far the best answer here, I would only suggest that you explain what's happening here. Also, the `.ajax__tab_outer` collection can be assigned to a variable outside that function to avoid repeating class name element lookups.

Comment: i would also like to know what's going on here. :)

Comment: "<%= TabContainer1.ClientID %>" this is a jsp scriptlet..if he has hard code id, then what?

Comment: Actually here missed one important tag for question it's ASP.NET related question. As I understand, its TabContainer control from the AjaxControlToolkit library. "<%= TabContainer1.ClientID %>" it's a common ASP.NET client-side expression for evaluating server controls id on the client side.

Comment: @HalfTrackMindMan: I copied the code but it doesn't change the color when I click on thidv. Indeed it's Ajaxcontrolpanel. <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" ../> why it doesn't change the color ???

Comment: @HalfTrackMindMan:  I assume it's because of <% %> client id etc.... Because if I remember well it's not advisable because that code of Client is renderend at later stage... could that be the reason?

Comment: No, that's was a minor bug here. Actually it's ok to use <%= %> expressions in client javascript because it not evaluated on client side but when on page rendered on server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd move away from AjaxToolkit and replace everything with jQuery. Add custom class to generated controls and bind events to that class. You can then use "this" keyword to work with an element which has been clicked.

**EDIT:**

Assign a class to all your tab containers.

class="my_class"

Then in event binding add `$('.my_class').live('click', myFunctionToChangeColours);` It's up to you whether you need to do a .live or .bind. After this in myFunctionToChangeColours you'd use "this" which I have mentioned before to change a colour of the tab that you have clicked on.

Comment: vikp, ok let's assume I remove ajaxtookit, but this is still the rendered code, when I replace the code with  "this.css("background-color", "#80FE80");" it doesn't change the color... My problem here is: I'm duplicating code... it should be shorter but how?

Comment: You'd have a single function to do this, rather than doing it in each tab container.

Answer (score 0):

place all your selectors(on which your are firing clcik event) in side an array,
then iterate that array,and bind a click event to all your selectors..that will make your code shorter.
you can make your resetColor() bit shorter in this way..

```
function resetColor(handler){
 $("#dnn_ctr8192_ViewWebShop_TabContainer1_"+handler+".ajax__tab_outer").css("background-color", "#edf2fb");
}
```

and then pass that middle words to that function like this(just an example).

```
resetColor(TabPanelVeiligheid_tab);
```

hope it helps you a bit!!